# jquery id selector with innerHtml or innerText or textContent

Tags: jquery

I writing a simple page to check if someone is entering the correct email twice.  I want to display in another element on the page weather or not the email in the second form block is the same as the first.  I'm using the jquery id selector.

```
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery1.8.3-min.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">


    function emailCheck(){
        if($("#email").val() != $("#email2").val())
        {
            $("#err").innerText = "emails don't match, sucka";
            $("#test").textContent = "emails don't match, sucka";
            $("#test2").innerHtml = "emails don't match, sucka";
            document.getElementById("getEleTest").innerText = "emails don't match, sucka";
            alert("dont match");
        }
    }
</script>
</head>

<body>
<form action="SignUp" method="POST">
    <table>
        <label for="email">Email</label></br>   
        <input id="email" type ="email" name="email1111"/> </br>
        <label for="email2" > Enter Email Again </label></br> 
        <input id="email2" type="email" name="email21111" onkeyup="emailCheck();"></br>
        <input type="submit" value="Sign Up">
    </table>
</form>

<div id="err"></div>
<div id="test"></div>
<div id="test2"></div>
<div id="getEleTest"></div>
</body>
```

In all cases I don't receive any text in the elements I am err, test, and test2 elements but i do get an alert window and there is text in the getEleTest element.  What could be going on here.  I don't get any errors in the firebug console, the jquery is getting the 'email' and 'email2' elements.  I've checked that I am linking the jquery script properly and just in case I haven't I added the google jquery source.  Thanks

Comment: How about a DOM ready function around that jQuery stuff to make it work, and stop using inline JS, like onclick functions ?

Comment: What would you use instead of the inline JS? I'm still a novice.

Comment: I've edited my answer to show you how to write it so you don't use inline JS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put all the jQuery stuff in `$(document).ready(function(){  //your code here });`

EDIT 2: I had a typo in my JS code. You were mixing regular JS with jQuery.

Why not write something like this?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#signUpForm").submit(function(evt){
        if($("#email").val() != $("#email2").val()){
            $("#err").html("emails don't match, sucka");
            $("#test").html("emails don't match, sucka");
            $("#test2").html("emails don't match, sucka");
            $("#getEleTest").html("emails don't match, sucka");
            alert("dont match");
            evt.preventDefault();
        };
    });
});​
```

and add id = "signUpForm" atribute to form? Also you need to remove inline JS from your HTML so your input doesn't have onKeyUp event.
You can see my example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/yp2pL/4/).

Comment: Not true - That is only for code which should run on page load. Ie: "document ready"

Comment: @Curt yeah, I just saw that. Also, why are you referencing jQuery twice?

Comment: You're setting the `innerText` and other properties on the jQuery wrapper, not the DOM element itself...

Comment: I referenced it twice because I wasn't sure if I was loading the local file properly so I decided to use the google version and just forgot to comment out the local one.  Why do you use the dom ready instead of inline JS?  How is it any better?

Comment: that isn't your problem. I've updated my code. You are mixing regular Javascript with jQuery. If you use jQuery you should instead of this `$("#err").innerText = "emails don't match, sucka";` write this `$("#err").text("emails don't match, sucka");`. @Dennis got it right...

Comment: @decapo [here](http://robertnyman.com/2008/11/20/why-inline-css-and-javascript-code-is-such-a-bad-thing/) is why inline JS is a bad idea.

Comment: I used $("#email2").bind('keyup', function emailCheck(){//code} to do it I didn't want it to check on submission just ask they were typing it in.

Comment: @decapo Yeah, that's alright too :) It's a matter of preference.

Answer (score 1):

It should either be:

```
document.getElementById("id").textContent = "string";
```

or

```
$("#id").text("string");
```

Make sure you don't combine the two or you won't get the expected result.

Answer (score 0):

write your code like this I have **tested** it on my machine

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function emailCheck(){
        if($("#email").val() != $("#email2").val())
        {
            $("#err").html("emails don't match, sucka");
            $("#test").html("emails don't match, sucka");
            $("#test2").html("emails don't match, sucka");

            document.getElementById("getEleTest").innerText = "emails don't match, sucka";
            //alert("dont match");
        }
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

All answers are partially right. You have to wrap your code in $(document).ready function, and then use the jQuery events, not the inline ones. The problem is that onkeyup doesn't work normally well with jQuery calls, as these are called in a function scope. 
I think the emailCheck function is not being called at all. Remove the **onkeyup** and try this, and work from there:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#email2').keyup( function() {
    alert("test");   
  });
});
```

Comment: I used  $("#email2").bind('keyup', function emailCheck(){//code} to do it thanks!